# Ubuntu 18.04 (4.15.0-177) booting issue: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e0

Tags: boot, 18.04, nvidia, pcie

I have a dual boot Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS + Windows 10 that has been working fine for 4 years, until yesterday.

Booting is now extremely slow (about 2 minutes compared with 15 seconds before) and when it finally boots, it seems like there is no graphics device or network device connected.
I'm also unable to change display settings like screen luminosity.

I ran `dmesg` and found this:

```
[  137.018944] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e0
[  137.018958] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e0(Receiver ID)
[  137.018967] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0:   device [8086:a110] error status/mask=00002001/00002000
[  137.018975] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0:    [ 0] Receiver Error         (First)
[  137.092114] pci_raw_set_power_state: 122 callbacks suppressed
[  137.092115] pcieport 0000:03:00.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
[  137.095913] pci_bus 0000:04: busn_res: [bus 04] is released
[  137.095950] pci_bus 0000:05: busn_res: [bus 05-39] is released
[  137.095981] pci_bus 0000:3a: busn_res: [bus 3a] is released
[  137.096112] pci_bus 0000:03: busn_res: [bus 03-3a] is released
```

[Link to the full dmesg](https://pastebin.com/S8RphZhR)

After waiting for about 5 minutes, the computer seem to find the graphic device, the display gets back to normal luminosity and the second monitor receives an image but there is still no network interface.

My kernel version is 4.15.0-177-generic.

I tried to add `pci=nomsi` and `pci=noaer` in the GRUB menu but the only effect it has is to make the keyboard unresponsive when I add `pci=noaer`.

Interestingly, booting with an older kernel (4.15.0-118-generic) seem to resolve the booting time and the network device issue. The GPU works too, but for some reason my second monitor doesn't receive anything and I am unable to access the nvidia driver settings because the window is empty:

[image: Nvidia settings window is empty]

[Link to the full dmesg (older kernel)](https://pastebin.com/6DH9rBgZ)

Comment: Did you find a resolution to this issue? I'm seeing similar issues with my dual boot machine after upgrading to 4.15.0-177. If I downgrade to 4.15.0-176 then things work fine, so it seems like it must have been introduced in 177.

Comment: I fixed the issue by upgrading my kernel to 5.4.0-177 and reinstalling gdm3. I would suggest to first try to reinstall gdm3 because I suspect this was the package causing the issue.

Comment: I have the same issue with 4.15.0-188, going back to 4.15.0-166 works fine. Same long booting, same nvidia X server setting window corrupted layout. It is on same dual boot machine sharing LTS 18.04 and Win10. Temporarily I therefore use 4.15.0-166.